# QGIS hexagonal grid size specifications

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, vector, hexagonal-grid

I am trying to understand how grid size/cell size is calculated while using "Create Grid" function in QGIS. According to https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-grid, the "horizontal spacing" is "Size of a grid cell on the X-axis" - but what is the size of cell in the hexagonal grid? It is not a short/long diagonal. It is not a 1/2 of the perimeter, it is not a radius, it is not an apothem - if I set horizontal/vertical spacing to 50m on EPSG:3857, I get these values:

[image]

Can the projection cause such a distortion, even if I am zoomed in on a 1:250m scale?

In ArcGIS Pro, one can easily create a hex grid by setting the area value, which is not possible in QGIS (not even via any plug-in I tried. Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: Uniform "area" hexagons in Web Mercator are useless because the true area is different for every row. Your difficulty is due to the distance-challenged projection (poles are infinitely far from the Equator) and most measurement tools being wise enough to ignore 3857 "meters".

Comment: I just redone everything in EPSG:5514 (used in CZ) and realised that horizontal spacing is the radius of the inscribed circle, while the escribed circle radius is vertical spacing.

Comment: Yes, the difference between `2R` and `2r` (where `R = r / sin(60)`). `d` is `2R`.

Comment: As a suggestion,  you could look into using Ubers H3 geography. Whilst it doesn't get round the issue of different hex sizes across space you can use the nested resolutions.